# How to enable a debug console in qt creator which can execute c++ expression during debug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, qt-creator, debug-console

i am new to the qt-IDE and trying to figure out, how to enable a debug console in qtcreator for my c++ project, which allow you to execute the c++ expression during the debug, for example like the vscode does:

Debug console in vscode:

[image: vscode-screenshoot]

QtCreator Version: 6.0.2
Operation System: Ubuntu 22.04.1
Build-tool: CMAKE

In qtcreator there is a "QML Debug console" which i always get a msg "can only evaluate during a debug session". Also the "Debugger Logs" from View->Views->Debugger Logs is inconvinience to use.

Comment: Do you want just to run a debugger or run a debug session in the console?

Comment: I want to run a debug session in the console within qtcreator, which can execute the c++ expression directly and see the return, e.g like the example in the screenshot of vscode.

Comment: In QtCreator, it is normal to use the integrated debugger (click the green arrow with a bug on it in the left-bottom corner). If you need a terminal, you open Linux/Widows terminal and run a standalone debugger like gdb (Linux). See for example: https://www.qt.io/resources/videos/debugging-and-profiling-inside-qt-creator